# Angular 10- IFrame throws error on reload

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

I am trying to load the html string from the api and update an iframe with the html string.
The code works fine for the first time. However, whenever **onBtnClick** method is called second time, it throws error:

```
VM3012:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared
    at SafeSubscriber._next (publishing.component.ts:88)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <div>
     <iframe #iframeRef width="100%" height="700px" (load)="onIframeLoad(iframeRef)" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
</div>
```

Component:

```
//Init
 iframeDoc$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

 onBtnClick():void{
 this.apiService.getHTMLString().subscribe(data => {
     iframeDoc.open();
     iframeDoc.write(`DDD<script>const x=1;</script>`);
     iframeDoc.close();
 });
 }

 getIframeDoc(): Observable<any> {
    return this.iframeDoc$.asObservable();
  }

  onIframeLoad(iframe): void {
    this.iframeDoc$.next(iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow);
  }
```

Comment: `x` is defined as a `const`. You cannot change it once you declare it. Maybe try with `let` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add same script again with some difference according to your data. Then you have to separate namespace.

`onBtnClick()` will create `const x = 1` on your iframe. Calling `onBtnClick()` will try to create `const x = 1` again in window object. Which is not correct since reassigning an new memory location is prohibited for `const` if you used `let` x will hold last memory assigned to `x`. If that is what you want then use it, but if will be confusing later time when you read it.

Now,
if you want it in a way that one script doesn't interfere with another you can do name spacing techniques.

one way is IIFE

```
iframeDoc.write(`DDD<script>
   (function () {
      const x = 1;

      your statements here....
   })();
</script>`);
```

Comment: In this case i dont have control over  the html as it comes from external website which has already const x=1 defined. Use case is i want to reload it/refresh the html on refresh btn clicked.

Comment: if it is only reload what you are looking for then do iframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true); OR iframe.src = iframe.src; will do it. You don't have to add additional script at all.